# TSQL - Sum a union query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a union all query in a stored procedure.

WHat I would like to do is Sum a column and return that query to the client

How would I do this?

Malcolm

Comment: I suggest you post your TSQL code

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
SELECT
    othercol1, othercol2,
    SUM(bar)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       othercol1, othercol2, bar
    FROM
       RT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       othercol1, othercol2, bar
    FROM
       FM
    ) foo
GROUP BY
    othercol1, othercol2
```

Comment: Is it better in **any** case to SELECT `othercol1, othercol2, SUM(bar)` rather than `othercol1, othercol2, bar` from the inner sub-query & SUM again in the outer query e.g. if the rows returned are too many i.e. thousands or millions? Or SUM() in the inner query will NEVER by better in any case?

Comment: @buffer: it would have 2 aggregate operations in the inner table, instead of one outer aggregate. It could be better.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT SUM(MyCol) FROM
(
SELECT ... MyCol FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ... MyCol FROM Table2
)as tbl
```

Comment: When using UNION you run the risk of an incorrect result ("union" when used by itself = "union distinct" which filters out duplicated rows), if summing it is much more likely that you need all rows, i.e. UNION ALL

Comment: @Used_By_Already - you're right, it should be UNION ALL of course.  Corrected.